# Method Post not working with Axios and React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am new in React.I am looking for how to save the data of a form with axios in a database. But not working..

My API.JS

```js
const axios = require ("axios");
const querystring = require('querystring');

export function getPeople(){
  return axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:9000/people`)
}

export function postPeople(){
  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:9000/people', querystring.stringify({
    'bar': 123
  }));
}
```

My app.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getPeople, postPeople } from './api';

addItem = () => {
    postPeople();
}
```

My Express.js:

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()


app.get('/people', cors(), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json([
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "0",
      age: 20,
      city: 'R0eiro',
      country: '04'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "0",
      age: 29,
      city: 'Minas 00',
      country: '00'
    },
})

app.listen(9000, function () {
  console.log('The server is running in the port 9000')
})
```

Be givin that errors:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:9000/people 404 (Not Found)
>
> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:9000/people: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

Someone help me?

Comment: Are you importing server-side code into your frontend?

Comment: Not, how i do this ?

Comment: There's nothing at http://127.0.0.1:9000/people . You are getting a 404 error, which means the server didn't have anything to serve at that address. Have you tried opening that link directly?

Comment: @acdcjunior Yes, i open and see the JSON..

Comment: The method `Get` is working..

Comment: You shouldn't. What's running on port 9000?

Comment: It seems to be a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem.

Comment: The `Express`, i going to update the question, and to add the `Express`

Comment: Really you should run a proxy in your react app to port `9000`, if you used create-react-app you can [set it up easily](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development).

Comment: @Jota, if one of the answers helped you, please checkmark the answer :]

Answer (score 2):

You're running into a CORS problem.

Taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa):

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)
>   header.
>
> When Site A tries to fetch content from Site B, Site B can send an
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to tell the browser that
>   the content of this page is accessible to certain origins. (An origin
>   is a domain, plus a scheme and port number.) By default, Site B's
>   pages are not accessible to any other origin; using the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header opens a door for cross-origin
>   access by specific requesting origins.
>
> For each resource/page that Site B wants to make accessible to Site A,
>   Site B should serve its pages with the response header:
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com Modern browsers will not
>   block cross-domain requests outright. If Site A requests a page from
>   Site B, the browser will actually fetch the requested page on the
>   network level and check if the response headers list Site A as a
>   permitted requester domain. If Site B has not indicated that Site A is
>   allowed to access this page, the browser will trigger the
>   XMLHttpRequest's error event and deny the response data to the
>   requesting JavaScript code.

You'll probably want a [cors npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors):

From the command like install cors:

```
npm install cors
```

Then in your API.js:

```
const axios = require ("axios");
const querystring = require('querystring');
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

export function getPeople(){
  return axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:9000/people`)
}

export function postPeople(){
  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:9000/people', querystring.stringify({
    'bar': 123
  }));
}
```

Comment: Would be like this?
`export function postPeople(){
  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:9000/people', cors(), querystring.stringify({
    'bar': 123
  }));
}`

Comment: @Jota No, you need `cors()` on the server side not the client side. In any case, the problem is that you're only listening for `GET` requests on path `/people`, you'll have to add `app.post(....)` on the server side.

Comment: @Jota, I updated the code to what I think it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting CORS errors because you're trying to make requests to a different port (which counts as a different domain). You could set up CORS headers as seen in the other answer, but:

A much better way is to use a proxy in your react app. See [Proxying API Requests](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development) if you are using [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

Then you would use the same port and just prefix with a `/api` route:

```
axios.post('/api/people', querystring.stringify({
  'bar': 123
}));
```